# Why won't my code invoke this method of the object?

Tags: javascript

There is an event handler in the body tag.

```
<body onload="hangmanGame.populateQuestions();">
```

It is supposed to get a random position of the array...

```
const hangmanGame = {
obtainRandom(x) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(x));
  },
populateQuestions() {
    let randNum = obtainRandom(5);
    let numToPopulate = stemQuestions[randNum];
    console.log(randNum);
    console.log(numToPopulate);
}, 
stemQuestions : ['What do roots of a quadratic equation represent in a parabola?',
                 'What is a chemical process where a solid turns into a gas without going through a liquid stage',
                 'What is the name of the peculiar kind of inheritance pertinent to JavaScript?',
                 'What is the product of mass and velocity?',
                 'What is acceleration with respect to velocity?'],
stemAnswers :  ['intercepts','sublimation','prototype','momentum','derivative']
```

}

But according to the console, both values are undefined...
Can you please give me some insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`obtainRandom` and `stemQuestions` are properties of `hangmanGame`, so in order to refer to them from inside `populateQuestions` you need to use `this`:

```
populateQuestions() {
    let randNum = this.obtainRandom(5);
    let numToPopulate = this.stemQuestions[randNum];
    console.log(randNum);
    console.log(numToPopulate);
}
```